# Запись в файл из класса битрикс

Tags: php, сервер, битрикс, хостинг

как записать в файл на сервере в папке сайта, в папке сервера? не записывается в файл папки сайта- выводит:" файл не создается".
Данный пример не записывает файл в папку сайта. Директория, где надо создать и записать файл, находится в корневой папке сайта.

```
$today = date("dmY");
$id_price_list=18;
$text="Прайс-лист ".$id_price_list." новый гуид ".$resAr['guid']." старый гуид ".$arDBElement["XML_ID"]."\r\n";

//$file="http://".SITE_SERVER_NAME."/logs_for_price_list/guid_1C_not_export/".$today.".txt";

$file="//logs_for_price_list/guid_1C_not_export/".$today.".txt";
echo $file;

$handle = fopen($file, "a");//Открываем для записи в конец.
if (!$handle) {
  echo "Oшибка: файл не создался-".$text;
} else {
  fputs ($handle, $text); 
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, сервер, где находится сайт, работает под Linux. Поэтому некорректная по сути запись пути `//logs_for_price_list/guid_1C_not_export/` указывает не на папку в корне сайта, а на папку в корне файловой системы сервера. И, естественно, такой папки нет. Не говоря уже о том, что запись туда для скриптов веб-приложения запрещена.

Чтобы записать файл в корень сайта, надо сначала определить корректный путь до этого корня. Обычно достаточно использовать `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`.  В Битриксе есть константа, хранящая этот путь: [SITE_DIR](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/constants.php)

А вот уже потом формируем путь до файла

```
 $file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/logs_for_price_list/guid_1C_not_export/" . $today . ".txt";
```

И, естественно, директория должна существовать, и у скрипта должны быть права для записи в эту директорию.